# Jitsi meet Video and Muted in IOS

Tags: ios, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Jitsi meet application configured and setup working correctly. Meeting working perfectly in all other platform except iOS.

The Jitsi on my browser and android is working really fine. But on iOS to iOS and iOS to Android and iOS to the web, there are mic and video default off. Video and mic are working fine within ios app, other can't see the iOS joined users.

Trying to solve this issue, not yet found any solution.

Comment: Did you found the solution to this ? If yes can you please explain. Thank you.

Comment: it can't work because the WKWebview doesn't support the getUserMedia() https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185448